# What is a correct way to structure adding event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a small personal project, and i use vanilla JS to control everything  on my front-end. I have 5 different routes and one `app.js` . This is how i currently add event listeners:

```
    function deleteTopic() {
    let btn = document.querySelector('.button-delete-topic')
    if (btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        ////////////do something
      })
    }
  }
```

It works well but my concern is that this function is called on all routes, even though `button-delete-topic`  is only on one route.  Is it a bad idea to add event listeners this way? Is it better to add separate `*.js` files for each route?  Thank you for  any advice.

Comment: Is `deleteTopic` only called when on that one route? If so, seems just fine to me

Comment: @CertainPerformance no it's called on all routes. And then `if(btn)` condition evaluates to false if there is no `button-delete-topic`

Comment: Sounds like you should change is so that `deleteTopic` is only called on that one route, rather than all

Comment: @CertainPerformance you mean with something like this `if (window.location.pathname === '/someRoute')` call that function ?

Comment: Sure. If a function only makes sense in the context of a certain page, make sure you're on that page before calling it. The larger the project is, the (much) more important and useful this is for code structuring.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you, and what about adding separate js files for each route ? Is it  a bad idea ?

Comment: I think that as long as you do it right, either method can work just fine, at least for anything other than large professional sites, for which there might be a more objective lean. If you're combining the scripts due to shared code, you can *probably* use a bundler like Webpack to output multiple .js files, if you want

Answer (score 0):

I would create a utility to handle these events.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (ev) {
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log(this.getAttribute('data-action'));
      // Check if data-action exists or do something with action
    });
}, true);
```

You could then use `data-attributes` to pass data.